# Python + selenium + XPATH

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть простой парсер, который в определенный момент вызывает функцию

```
object = browser.find_element_by_xpath(***ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ***)
```

получаю объект типа FirefoxWebElement, и вывожу его значение

```
object.text()
```

Однако я получаю только первый элемент по данному запросу, каким образом в selenium-e можно получитьвсе объекты по xpath? 
(Это же выражение в GRAB-e отдаёт верное значение, если вызывать grab.xpath_list) Есть ли аналог в Selenium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [find_element**s**_by_xpath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), чтобы получить список элементов.

Тогда, выражение будет:

```
object_list = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(***ВЫРАЖЕНИЕ***)
for el in object_list:
    print(el.text)
```

Comment: В данный ответ необходимо добавить пример использования указанной функции.

Comment: @Темкатоже кому необходимо? :)